# Errors when linking libsodium.a into a Shared Object

Tags: c++, c++11, linker, g++

I am trying to use the libsodium library in a C++ project and I'm having difficulty with linking the static Libsodium Library into a Shared Object that I've created. This project is being compiled using G++ and is set to use C++11 Standards.

After reading various forum posts about linking a Static Library into a Shared Object, I've tried using the Whole Archive which seems to get me further but still will not link in correctly.

The following is the Command being used to link:

```
/usr/bin/g++ -shared -fPIC -o ./Debug/libwowcrypt.so @"libwowcrypt.txt" -L. -L../SharedLibraries/Sodium/lib   -Wl,--whole-archive -lsodium -Wl,--no-whole-archive
```

The following error messages are returned from ld:

```
/usr/bin/ld: ../SharedLibraries/Sodium/lib/libsodium.a(libsodium_la-hmac_hmacsha256.o): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `crypto_auth_hmacsha256_init' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Can anyone advise on the correct linker flags that are needed to incorporate this static library into my shared object?

Comment: I am running into the same issue .. did you find anything yet ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ran into the same problem. Assuming you are on Ubuntu < 15.04 (mine is 14.04 LTS), you need to disable PIE

`./configure --disable-pie`

and then the usual: `make` / `make install` etc.

Now you should be able to link the static `libsodium.a` to your `.so`. I got this from a recent discussion on [github issue i raised here](https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium/issues/292)